# Sets and topology

Tags: real-analysis, general-topology

Let $A$⊂ $\mathbb {R}$ be a nonempty and bounded subset of $\mathbb {R}$. Prove that sup $A$ ∈ $\bar{A}$. Note that $\mathbb {R}$ is equipped with its usual distance.

Comment: What is the definition of $\sup?$ What is the definition of point of closure? What have you tried?

Comment: What about something like "Take a sequence of elements in $A$ converging to sup $A$. By definition, the limit is in the closure"?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Suppose $O$ is a neighbourhood of $\sup(A)$ in the reals. We can take $r>0$ such that $(\sup(A) -r, \sup(A) +r) \subseteq O$.

Now ask yourself, why should there be any points $a$ from $A$  with $\sup(A)-r < a \le \sup(A)$? If so, we see $O$ intersects $A$, and so $\sup(A) \in \overline{A}$.

Comment: take r= sup A - y where y<sup A does this clarify the point?

Comment: @Karen no. You need the definition of $\sup(A)$.